# CloudKit CKRecord Deletion - How to Obtain RecordIDs

Tags: swift, cloudkit

For the app I'm working on, a user can create an account and can create posts for other users to see.

I want to provide the option for users to delete their account & posts but see that the record deletion function requires the object's recordID (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckdatabase/1449122-delete).

Is there a way I can retrieve and save the CloudKit generated recordID metadata for records, so the recordIDs can be utilized for record deletion later?

I've tried things like the following to no avail:

```
let rN = record.object(forKey: "recordName") as? String ?? nil
            
if let recordName = rN
{
     personP.recordID = CKRecord.ID.init(recordName: recordName)
}
```

For some more context, I've been using a separate String field as an identifier for users to fetch their existing account/posts when they log into the app.

Alternatively: is there a way to delete records without needing the CKrecordID (for example, being able to delete all records returned from a CKQueryOperation)?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `fetch(withRecordID:completionHandler:)` to get an array of all records along with their record IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that you can leverage the NSManagedObjectID of an entity to obtain its recordID (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer/3141669-recordid)

Example use for creating an array of recordIDs for an entity called "Post":

```
var recordIDArray = [CKRecord.ID]()

let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Post")
let requestPredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

fetchRequest.predicate = requestPredicate

moc.performAndWait
{
    let result = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for data in result as! [NSManagedObject]
    {
        let recordID = CoreDataModel.persistenceContainer.recordID(for:data.objectID)
        
        if let rID = recordID
        {
            recordIDArray.append(rID)
            print("record ID for a post is \(String(describing: rID))")
        }
    }
}
```